# How to implement PromiseLike interface?

Tags: typescript

I try to implement a auto-commit process with thenable support. But I cannot walk around the type error complained in the last occasion:

```
type JobResolve = () => void

export class Job implements PromiseLike<JobResolve> {
  public then<TResult1 = JobResolve>(onfulfilled?: ((value: JobResolve) => (PromiseLike<TResult1> | TResult1)) | undefined | null): PromiseLike<TResult1> {
    const done = () => {}
    if (typeof onfulfilled === 'function') {
      const thenable = Promise.resolve(onfulfilled(done))
      done()
      return thenable
    } else {
      // Error here!
      // TS2322: '() => void' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TResult1', but 'TResult1' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
      return Promise.resolve(done)
    }
  }
}
```

How to solve it? (without `Promise.resolve(done as any)`)

Comment: I think this is the classic generics problem where you need to create something of the generic type, but of course, you don't have a concrete view of the final generic type (it's definitely `JobResolve` in `Job`, but a `Job` subclass could make it something else, and then `done` wouldn't be the right type).

Comment: (BTW, the `if` branch looks a bit off -- `done` gets called twice...although since it doesn't do anything, it doesn't really matter. I assume it actually does something in your real code, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` branch shows a weakness in the definition on `PromiseLike`.
Consider [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsLwBQEoYDeAUDKTADYCmyMyAXIcAyMgE6oQDmAvjALwxgAd2CoaABVboAtqhCUAdK0oh05AG6VsARlwLkAC0oQAPASYwW7LtwB8eANwkyUTKqoLy6TtmQAaWgVgAOQwAAdKdDhaEPDI6OQg3CduIjhHIA).

```js
async function f() {
    let t: {a: string} = await Promise.resolve(1).then<{a: string}>();
    console.log(t, t.a, typeof t, typeof t.a);
}
f();
```

`t` is of type `number` not `object`, but the type system thinks it's an object.

If your aim is to provide compliance with `Promise`, your might as well just cast your returned value to the return type as in:

```js
    return Promise.resolve(done) as PromiseLike<TResult1>
```

or, to be safer, throw an exception.